# Filter options in smartsheet API or SDK

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I am currently exploring the [smartsheet API 2.0](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/). I want to filter based on Modified and Created date but I am unable to find any such option in the documentation.

Is there a way out to filter the smartsheet using any custom filter as we have in oData API. e.g
`<API URL>?$filter= createdDate ge '10/06/2019' or modified ge '10/06/2019'`

Comment: Could you find a way to activate filters on api calls?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your filters in smartsheet since they can not be created on wire over API.
Then you can call

```
https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{id}?filterId={ID}&exclude=filteredOutRows
```

P.S You need to enter id of your filter not the name of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [sheet filter](https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/504659-using-filters-to-show-or-hide-sheet-data), and then filter the rows via the API using the `include=filters` param.

[See the docs for more details.](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#filters-object)

Comment: include=filters does not filter our rows actually, according to docs "include=filters query string, which returns a row.filteredOut = true or false response for rows that are excluded by a filter."

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to send a filter query, some alternatives :

- You can create a filter on the fly such as described below.
- Or you can read all the sheet content and then filter on you own

In c# filtering row would look like this:

```
var ssclient = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(token).Build();
m.Sheet sheet = ssclient.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
List<m.Row> rowsModifiedToday = sheet.Rows.Where(r => DateTime.ParseExact(r.Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString(), "dd/MM/yy", null) >= DateTime.Today).ToList();
```